# alsa not playing the complete file

Tags: audio, alsa, pcm, pulseaudio

I am trying to read a wave file and play it on one of the sound cards on the board. Below is the code. I am facing several problems with this code.

1. I am trying to play files with various sample rates. With a file of Sampling rate of 8KHz, File doesn't play completely, even though the file dump shows entire content of the file.
2. If I play a file of 11025 Hz, I hear only noise
3. For stereo data I get garbled audio.

PS :

1. I am setting the rate obtained from the wave header
2. Period size is set to 10 ms. i.e for 16KHz - 160; 11025 - 110

   ```
   ret = snd_pcm_open(&handlePCMHD, "hw:0,0",
       SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
   if (ret < 0) {
       snd_pcm_close(handlePCMHD);
       return -1;
   }

   fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
   /* file dump */
   fd2 = open("test.raw", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
   if(fd < 0)
   {
       return -1;
   }

   /* Wave file header is 44 bytes */
   if(read(fd, buf, 44)){
       sampleRate = buf[12] | ((unsigned int)buf[13] << 16);

       channels = buf[11];
   }else{
       //read failed
   }

   set_pcmhd_hw_param(handlePCMHD, sampleRate);

   /* Buffer size = SampleRate * Number of Bytes per frame * No of Periods / For 10 ms */
   readBytes = (sampleRate * 2 * 2)/100;

   while((channels == 1) ? (x = read(fd, buf, readBytes)) : (x = read(fd, stereobuf, readBytes * 2)))
   {
       if(channels == 2){
           StereoToMono_samples(buf ,stereobuf, readBytes/2);
       }
       write(fd2, buf, readBytes);
       /* Number of frames = read bytes / 2 for 16 bit PCM */
       x = readBytes / 2;
       if ((ret = snd_pcm_writei(handlePCMHD, buf, (snd_pcm_uframes_t)x) == -EPIPE)) {
           snd_pcm_prepare(handlePCMHD);
       } else if (ret < 0) {
           //error handling
       } else{
           count++;
       }
   }
   close(fd);
   close(fd2);
   snd_pcm_close(handlePCMHD);
   ```

Comment: What does `set_pcmhd_hw_param()` do? How does it know the number of channels and bits?

Comment: For current testing number of channels and data format is fixed. set_pcmhd_hw_param() just sets these values apart from rate and period

Comment: channel = 1 , bits = S16_LE for this testing

Comment: And does your hardware support this?

Comment: Yes, the Hardware currently only supports 1 channel and S16_LE